# Ban ip for deny access to an app

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

I have an application (.war) deployed in a Websphere Application Server v8. This app consists in a web application which is accessed by browser.

Now I have an IP Address that I want to ban but I don't find the option in the Administrative Console. Where I should ban this ip for to avoid the access this specifically application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WebSphere you have 2 options (depends if you directly access app server or through http server):

1 Directly via WebSphere admin console.

Go to:

- Application servers > server1 > Web container transport chains > WCInboundDefault > TCP inbound channel (TCP_2)
- In the `Address exclude list` enter client addresses you want to block
- restart the server

2 Use IBM HTTP Server (based on Apache) and WebSphere Plugin, which is available with WebSphere and define Deny list using standard httpd.conf configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an IP filter isn't implemented by default in your application server, but it's easy enough to include an IP filter implemented in a servlet filter.

There's a nice intro to what filters can do on [the Oracle site](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) and plenty of readymade IP filters all over the web, like [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Servlets/IPFilter.htm) or [here](https://github.com/binarybirchtree/servlet-ip-filter).  As you can see, the code needed is pretty simple, and as servlet filters are part of the EE spec, the result is portable between appservers as well.