# Websphere server config to allow requests from specific IP or systems

Tags: proxy, websphere, websphere-7, whitelist

I heard from somewhere WebSphere server can be configured to allow only a pre-defined set systems (IPs, domains) to access server contents such as WSDL.

Need help with following questions:

1. Is this supported?
2. What are the steps to do the same?
3. Prerequisites?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Check this post [Ban ip for deny access to an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24137145/ban-ip-for-deny-access-to-an-app). It describes various methods (configuring transport channels, http server, or developing custom filter). Although it talks about banning access, same technique can be applied to allow access.

Take notice however that using transport channel will apply to all applications and resources available via given port (not just wsdl). So the solution depends on level of granularity you require.

Comment: Thank you Gas for referencing to right answer! This is what I was looking for.